# Can't add a tooltip to a list element

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a list element that is coded with Angular that shows all the cars and I want to add a tooltip to the top left corner of it.

What I've tried:

```
I made a span tag with class "tooltip" that encapsulates the ul. I added the "position: 
relative" property with css. Then I placed a span tag inside the list element and added the 
text I would place inside the tooltip and added the "display: none" property using css. Then I 
placed some css codes so that the tooltip appears when hovering over this list element with 
css. You will find below.
```

Note: the list element I want to show tooltip when hovering: "All Brands"

brand.component.html:

```
   <span class="tooltip">
        <ul *ngIf="dataLoaded==true" class="list-group">
            <li (click)="currentBrand=null" routerLink="/cars" class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="{'active': !currentBrand}">
                <span class="text">
                    Listed All Cars
                </span> 
                All Brands
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" (click)="currentBrand = brand" routerLink="/cars/brand/{{brand.brandId}}" [ngClass]="{'active': currentBrand === brand}" *ngFor="let brand of brands">{{brand.brandName}}</li>
        </ul>
    </span>
```

brand.component.css:

```
/* Tooltip */

.tooltip {
    position: relative;
}

ul li:first-child .text {
    display: none;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 1px;
    z-index: 1;
}

ul li:first-child:hover ul li:first-child .text {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}

ul li:first-child .text::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 110%;
    right: 90%;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

I look forward to your help and advice if any.

Answer (score 0):

fixed css. tool tip text must be "visibility: hidden;" and not none

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 1px;
    z-index: 1;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
span: {
    display: none;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 1px;
    z-index: 1;
}



ul li:first-child:hover ul li:first-child .text {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}

ul li:first-child .text::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 110%;
    right: 90%;
    border: 5px solid;
    border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

</style>
<span class="tooltip">
        <ul *ngIf="dataLoaded==true" class="list-group">
            <li (click)="currentBrand=null" routerLink="/cars" class="list-group-item" [ngClass]="{'active': !currentBrand}">
                <span class="tooltiptext">
                    Listed All Cars
                </span> 
                All Brands
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item" (click)="currentBrand = brand" routerLink="/cars/brand/{{brand.brandId}}" [ngClass]="{'active': currentBrand === brand}" *ngFor="let brand of brands">{{brand.brandName}}</li>
        </ul>
    </span>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't work your solution. I refactor your code a little bit but it can't work.